# Use delegate from multiple classes and methods

Tags: c#, class, methods, delegates, progress

How can I send values between different methods from other classes?

I have different classes which controls products on a website. So I have a classes for products, categories, images etc. From the Product-class I have a method to delete a product which calls the Images-class to delete the images from the product.
I would like to show the progress of the images which are deleted and afterwards continue deleting the product details or other attachments suchs as pdf-files. But there are other methods from other classes which can call the Images-class to delete images or just 1 images. From this point on, I have a form where I can delete a product where I would like to show the progress on a label.
Also, most methods are async and the classes containing a public delegate ProgressUpdate(int counterProduct, int counterTotal, string text) and a Public event ProgressUpdate onProgressUpdate.

In my form I have:

```cs
public async Task<bool> deleteProducts(List<int> products)
{
    foreach (var product in products)
    {
        Products prdct = new Products();
        var isProductDeleted = await Products.deleteProduct(product);
        if (isProductDeleted)
        {
            var isDeleted = await I.DeleteImages(product);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

In the Products-class:

```cs
class Products
{
public static async Task<bool> deleteProduct(int idProduct, int idShop = 1)
{
    if (idProduct > 0)
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM ps_product WHERE id_product = " + idProduct + ";";
        Database db = new Database();
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table = db.SelectWebsiteQuery(query);
        if(table.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            //Things to delete
            //First check if this product is not assigned to an order
            //ps_product :Check
            //ps_product_attachment : check
            //ps_product_carrier : check
            //ps_product_lang : check
            //ps_product_sale : check
            //ps_product_shop : check
            //ps_product_supplier : check
            //ps_product_tag : check
            //ps_revws_criterion : Not necessary
            //ps_revws_criterion_category : Not necessary
            //ps_revws_criterion_lang : Not necessary
            //ps_revws_criterion_product : check
            //ps_revws_review : ok
            //ps_revws_review_grade : ok
            //ps_revws_review_image : ok
            //ps_revws_review_reaction : ok
            //ps_search_index and update ps_search_word
            //ps_specific_price : ok
            //ps_specific_price_priority : ok
            //ps_stock_available : ok
            //ps_stock_mvt
            //ps_image
            //ps_image_lang : ok
            //ps_image_shop
            //ps_feature_product
            //ps_category_product
            int id_product = Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[0]["id_product"]);
            int id_supplier = Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[0]["id_supplier"]);
            int id_category_default = Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[0]["id_category_default"]);
            DataTable productDelete = new DataTable();
            //Check if this product has been ordered. If so, you can't delete it because it won't be visible in the order history
            query = "SELECT * FROM ps_order_detail WHERE product_id = " + idProduct + ";";
            productDelete = db.SelectWebsiteQuery(query);
            if(productDelete.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                //First delete the images
                query = "SELECT id_image FROM ps_image WHERE id_product = " + id_product + ";";
                productDelete = db.SelectWebsiteQuery(query);
                
                if(db.InsertWebsiteQuery("DELETE FROM ps_product WHERE id_product = " + idProduct + ";") == 1)
                {
                    query = "SELECT attachment FROM ps_product_attachment WHERE id_product = " + idProduct + ";";
                    productDelete = db.SelectWebsiteQuery(query);
                    if(productDelete.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        for(int a = 0; a < productDelete.Rows.Count; a++)
                        {
                            string attachmentName = productDelete.Rows[a]["attachment"].ToString();
                            await Ftp.DeleteFile(Properties.Settings.Default.FtpWebHost, Properties.Settings.Default.FtpWebUsername, Properties.Settings.Default.FtpWebPassword,
                                           Properties.Settings.Default.DownloadPath, attachmentName, Properties.Settings.Default.FtpWebSsh);
                        }
                    }
                    db.InsertWebsiteQuery("DELETE FROM ps_product_carrier WHERE id_product = " + idProduct + ";");
                    db.InsertWebsiteQuery("DELETE FROM ps_product_lang WHERE id_product = " + idProduct + ";");
                    db.InsertWebsiteQuery("DELETE FROM ps_product_sale WHERE id_product = " + idProduct + ";");
                    db.InsertWebsiteQuery("DELETE FROM ps_product_shop WHERE id_product = " + idProduct + ";");
                    db.InsertWebsiteQuery("DELETE FROM ps_product_supplier WHERE id_product = " + idProduct + ";");
                    db.InsertWebsiteQuery("DELETE FROM ps_product_tag WHERE id_product = " + idProduct + ";");
                    db.InsertWebsiteQuery("DELETE FROM ps_revws_criterion_product WHERE id_product = " + idProduct + ";");
                    db.InsertWebsiteQuery("DELETE FROM ps_specific_price WHERE id_product = " + idProduct + ";");
                    db.InsertWebsiteQuery("DELETE FROM ps_specific_price_priority WHERE id_product = " + idProduct + ";");
                    db.InsertWebsiteQuery("DELETE FROM ps_stock_available WHERE id_product = " + idProduct + ";");
                    query = "SELECT * FROM ps_image WHERE id_product = " + idProduct + ";";
                    table = db.SelectWebsiteQuery(query);
                    for(int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        int idImage = Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[i]["id_image"]);
                        db.InsertWebsiteQuery("DELETE FROM ps_image_lang WHERE id_image = " + idImage + ";");
                        db.InsertWebsiteQuery("DELETE FROM ps_image_shop WHERE id_product = " + idProduct + " AND id_image = " + idImage + " AND id_shop = " + idShop + ";");
                    }

                    //Now delete all images
                    // From here I would like to have a response from the Images-class of the progress...
                    Images images = new Images();
                    var isDeleted = await images.DeleteImages(idProduct);

                    //Reorder product position
                    Category category = new Category();
                    category.reOrderProductCategory(idProduct);
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

And in my Images-class:

```cs
class Images
{
    //Thread shit
    public delegate void ProgressUpdate(int counterProduct, int counterTotal, string text);
    public event ProgressUpdate onProgressUpdate;
    public bool CancelThread = false;
public async Task<bool> DeleteImages(int idProduct = 0, int idImage = 0, int idCategory = 0)
{
    if (idProduct > 0 && idImage > 0 && idCategory > 0)
    {
        List<string> imageNames = new List<string>();
        Database db = new Database();
        string query = "";
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        //First load the image-names from the image_type table depending on idProduct and idImage or idCategory
        query = "SELECT `name` FROM ps_image_type WHERE " + (idCategory > 0 ? "categories" : "products" ) + " = 1;";
        table = db.SelectWebsiteQuery(query);
        if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            //Load the names in the list
            for(int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string imageName = table.Rows[i]["name"].ToString();
                imageName = imageName.Trim();
                imageNames.Add(imageName);
            }

            //Delete all images from product
            if (idProduct > 0 && idImage < 1 && idCategory < 1)
            {
                onProgressUpdate?.Invoke(0, 0, "Getting images to delete...");
                query = "SELECT id_image FROM ps_image WHERE id_product = " + idProduct + ";";
                table = db.SelectWebsiteQuery(query);
                if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        string imagePath = Properties.Settings.Default.FtpImagePath;
                        int id_image = Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[i]["id_image"].ToString());
                        string productImagePath = GetImagePath(id_image, imagePath);
                        for(int n = 0; n < imageNames.Count; n++)
                        {
                            string name = imageNames[n].ToString();
                            if(n == 0)
                            {
                                onProgressUpdate?.Invoke(idProduct, table.Rows.Count, "Deleting image: " + id_image.ToString() + ".jpg");
                                await Ftp.DeleteFile(Properties.Settings.Default.FtpWebHost, Properties.Settings.Default.FtpWebUsername, Properties.Settings.Default.FtpWebPassword, productImagePath,
                                    id_image.ToString() + ".jpg", Properties.Settings.Default.FtpWebSsh);
                            }
                            await Ftp.DeleteFile(Properties.Settings.Default.FtpWebHost, Properties.Settings.Default.FtpWebUsername, Properties.Settings.Default.FtpWebPassword, productImagePath,
                                    id_image.ToString() + "-" + name + ".jpg", Properties.Settings.Default.FtpWebSsh);
                            onProgressUpdate?.Invoke(idProduct, table.Rows.Count, "Deleting image: " + id_image.ToString() + "-" + name + ".jpg");
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else if (idProduct < 1 && idImage > 0 && idCategory < 1)//Delete a selected image
            {
                string imagePath = Properties.Settings.Default.FtpImagePath;
                int id_image = idImage;
                string productImagePath = GetImagePath(id_image, imagePath);
                for (int n = 0; n < imageNames.Count; n++)
                {
                    string name = imageNames[n].ToString();
                    if (n == 0)
                    {
                        await Ftp.DeleteFile(Properties.Settings.Default.FtpWebHost, Properties.Settings.Default.FtpWebUsername, Properties.Settings.Default.FtpWebPassword, productImagePath,
                            id_image.ToString() + ".jpg", Properties.Settings.Default.FtpWebSsh);
                    }
                    await Ftp.DeleteFile(Properties.Settings.Default.FtpWebHost, Properties.Settings.Default.FtpWebUsername, Properties.Settings.Default.FtpWebPassword, productImagePath,
                            id_image.ToString() + "-" + name + ".jpg", Properties.Settings.Default.FtpWebSsh);
                }
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                string imagePath = Properties.Settings.Default.FtpCategoryPath;
                int id_category = idCategory;
                string categoryImagePath = GetImagePath(id_category, imagePath);
                for (int n = 0; n < imageNames.Count; n++)
                {
                    string name = imageNames[n].ToString();
                    if (n == 0)
                    {
                        await Ftp.DeleteFile(Properties.Settings.Default.FtpWebHost, Properties.Settings.Default.FtpWebUsername, Properties.Settings.Default.FtpWebPassword, categoryImagePath,
                            id_category.ToString() + ".jpg", Properties.Settings.Default.FtpWebSsh);
                    }
                    await Ftp.DeleteFile(Properties.Settings.Default.FtpWebHost, Properties.Settings.Default.FtpWebUsername, Properties.Settings.Default.FtpWebPassword, categoryImagePath,
                            id_category.ToString() + "-" + name + ".jpg", Properties.Settings.Default.FtpWebSsh);
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await Task.Run(async () => await Email.sendEmail(Properties.Settings.Default.EmailLogAddress, "No image types found for the given values in DeleteImages", 
                                                       "No names found for the image-types with image-type: " + (idCategory > 0 ? "categories." : "products."), true, ""));
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that the main issue is the structure of your methods. Presently, `deleteProduct` and `DeleteImages` handle multiple use cases at once and run large workflows. You would benefit by breaking these into discrete functions that have a smaller scope of responsibility. You can still keep your existing workflow functions but instead they will also use these discrete functions. Refactoring in this way increases flexibility and also readability. This should make it much easier to handle the problem you're running into.

Comment: Yes @GenericUser you are absolutely right. My thoughts where to minimize the amount of code by combining it to one function. I will divide it to separate functions.
I just made a new test-project and added 2 classes with public delegates and events.
From the main-form, I created a new instance of the 1st class and declared an event for the progress. And in the 1st class I also created a new instance of the 2nd class and declared an event for that one. This all works well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I already found how to do this from other classes. Here is a little example.
In your form button click:

```cs
private async void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Counter counter = new Counter();
    counter.onProgressUpdate += new Counter.ProgressUpdate(C_onProgressUpdate);
    var isCounting = await counter.CountNumbers();
}

private void C_onProgressUpdate(int progress)
{
    base.Invoke((Action)delegate
    {
        lblValue.Text = progress.ToString();
    });
}
```

In the first class named Counter:

```cs
public delegate void ProgressUpdate(int counter);
public event ProgressUpdate onProgressUpdate;
public async Task<bool> CountNumbers()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        onProgressUpdate?.Invoke(i);
        if(i == 20)
        {
            CounterSecond counterSecond = new CounterSecond();
            counterSecond.onProgressUpdate += CounterSecond_onProgressUpdate;
            await counterSecond.countNext();
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private void CounterSecond_onProgressUpdate(int counter)
{
    if(onProgressUpdate != null)
    {
        onProgressUpdate(counter);
    }
}
```

In your second class named CounterSecond.

```cs
public delegate void ProgressUpdate(int counter);
public event ProgressUpdate onProgressUpdate;

public async Task<bool> countNext()
{
    for (int i = 100; i < 150; i++)
    {

        await Task.Delay(100);
        onProgressUpdate?.Invoke(i);
    }
    return true;
}
```